# React native expo fetching data from API Network Request Failed error

Tags: api, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm currently trying to run this code

```
        fetch('http://112.134.77.211:8080/users/toFrontend?email=baby@gmail.com')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
            this.setState({ data: json.movies });
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
          });
      }
```

The backend is locally run on spring boot and the database is on google cloud every time I run the code i get a Network Request Failed error

Comment: have you try run it on your browser? what do you get?

Comment: @slashsharp I do get the correct output in the browser

Comment: Are you testing on Android 9+?

Comment: @Bored no I'm using 8.1

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm having a similar problem and can't figure out why...